# Why are rogues always depicted wearing so many belts?

Tags: rogue, larp, art

I have no idea where to put this, but I had a player ask a really good question about rogues:

**Why are they always depicted wearing so many belts?**

I've been googling this for a few hours, and while I think there is a reason beyond the "Many Belts" TV trope, I can't find it.  What is this about?  Why are rogues/thieves so commonly depicted wearing so many belts?

[image: a rogue-looking LARPer wearing at least six belts, several of them just for aesthetics.]

Comment: Where have you seen so many rogues wearing so many belts?

Comment: Everyone knows that sorcerers are the ones with belts - http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/forgottenrealms/images/b/b8/Hennet_Sam-Wood_PHB3e.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20140912004315

Comment: I don't think this is primarily opinion based. Imho the rogue-with-many-belts-and-pouches is a long-standing trope and asking where it comes from has a non-opinion-based answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

They don't usually wear **that** many, but generally speaking, Rogues are the stereotypical "prepared for everything" character. They need belts because belts means pouches and other storage locations for stuff. And they have lots of stuff.

As a Rogue, you need room for lockpicks, skeleton keys, daggers, trap-disabling tools, smokebombs, caltrops, coins and gems, poisons, acids, mirrors, and who knows what other things you need when you're a dungeon-looting badass.

As a result, they have more belts and pouches and other storage kits than most people. Which then becomes a stereotype in itself, and so people start to exaggerate.